# How can I determine which application is using a given camera?

Tags: macos, webcam

I have a MacBook Pro hooked up to an Apple Cinema Display.  It is **very** common for the external display's camera to be unavailable to my apps.

Since I do not reboot often, it seems very possible that an app (or its background process!) that is not actively using the camera is still locking it.

Figuring out what's using it (if anything) seems like the first step in determining why I can't use the camera I want, when I want it.

Comment: is it not equally likely it 'lost' it after sleeping?

Comment: maybe, why do you suspect that?

Comment: Just based on the number of 'my Mac lost connection to xyz after sleeping' questions we see on here.

Comment: I've since discovered that this has a patchwork of answers on other SE sites.  I'm not sure why anyone would have asked an Apple-specific question elsewhere, or why they were not migrated, but I can see a case for closing this question if those questions are migrated to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: That would need quite some organising. Need the OP to request to migrate & need admins to do it. SuperUser, btw, would be perfectly on-topic for the same question, so the lines can blur.